# Deploy folder/files to Web Application Root

Tags: visual-studio, solution-package, web-application, solution-deployment

How to deploy folder to a SharePoint 2010 Web Application Root folder (inside inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80) in the solution package(wsp)?

Which kind of item I should use in the visual studio project? because nothing is mapped to {WebApplicationRoot} directly!!

Comment: Generally you don't deploy to the web app root, what are you doing?

Comment: It's an asp.net chat application (I don't its code) and I must work from the root of the web application folder and it's hard coded to get the images, css,.. from the Application Path `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`

Answer (score 1):

As the comments mention, you generally do not deploy files randomly in SharePoint as there is a specific structure that SharePoint expects at the root of a site.  If you must do something like this, you might want to move it to a subdomain outside of SharePoint like chat.domain.com where domain.com points to sharePoint and chat.domain.com points to a regular IIS website that hosts the chat application.  You could then add links/iframes in SharePoint to call the chat application.

From the Visual Studio side, you would treat it as a normal web application project.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to deploy the files to _layout folder and copy it in the FeatureActivated.